# Access denied to com port after opening 2nd form C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

When I open Form1 I can access the com port fine with out issue. I have a button on Form1 that opens Form2. When Form2 is opened I get "Access to the port 'COM4' is denied." on Form1. Here is call for opening the COM port.

```
private void GeneralTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (firstRun == 0)
        {
            init();
        }
        string selectedItem;
        selectedItem = comSelect.Text;
        updateSpeed();

        Fan1Val.Value = Convert.ToInt32(Fan1Val.Value);
        Fan2Val.Value = Convert.ToInt32(Fan2Val.Value);

        if (selectedItem != null && (selectedItem.Contains("COM")))
        {
            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                if (COMPORT != selectedItem)
                {
                    COMPORT = selectedItem;
                    serialPort1.PortName = selectedItem;
                    saveToFile("bin", "com", COMPORT);
                }
                serialPort1.Open(); //<----- I get the error on this line

            }
            updateRPMs();

        }
    }
```

Here is how I open Form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form2 form2 = new Form2("Fan1");
        form2.ShowDialog();



    }
```

I am new to C# and any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

Both code blocks are in Form1 and I am not trying to access the COM port from From2.

Comment: Is it already open from the first form? You can't open it twice... You need to remember to close the COM port whenever you open it, not closing it can cause problems (even on subsequent program restarts, it may think the port is open somewhere else).

Comment: @Ron  The second form does not open it, and I only open it if it is not already. The program closes the port, before the program closes.

Comment: So where do you pass the opened instance from the first form to the second form to use? You can't just create a new `SerialPort` with the same port name and expect the state to carry across instances.

Comment: I am not trying to use the serial port on the second form. It is just to update a text file. When the program is running Form1 opens first and open the port. Then when Form2 is opened Form one stays open in the background, and I get an error on Form1. I never tried to open the port with Form2.

Comment: I guess its not clear from how you posted which form these methods are in, I thought you were posting the code from Form2.

Comment: I have tried using 'show'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this is the fix, but I was referencing Form1 in form2 to use 2 functions in Form1. After removing the reference and copying the two functions over to form 2 it seems to work.

Works:

```
namespace FanHubController
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 mainForm = new Form1();

    public Form2(String currFan)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        currFanBox.Text = currFan;

    }
    public void saveToFile(String path, String fileName, String data)
    {
        String appLoc = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        String fullPath = appLoc + "\\" + path + "\\" + fileName + ".txt";

        string createText = data;
        File.WriteAllText(fullPath, createText);
    }

    public String readFile(String path, String fileName)
    {
        String appLoc = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        String fullPath = appLoc + "\\" + path + "\\" + fileName + ".txt";
        if (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (readFile("bin", "fanSpeeds") != null)
        {
            String[] allData = readFile("bin", "fanSpeed").Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2("");
        form2.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Does not Work:

```
namespace FanHubController
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 mainForm = new Form1();

    public Form2(String currFan)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        currFanBox.Text = currFan;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (mainForm.readFile("bin", "fanSpeeds") != null)
        {
            String[] allData = mainForm.readFile("bin", "fanSpeed").Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2("");
        form2.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You create a second Form1 when you instantiate a Form2. What happens is that this also creates another serial port object. Unfortunately the original Form1 has already opened that port and when the timer fires off for the duplicate Form1 it tries to open that same port from a different object and there is the conflict. Change `Form1 mainform = new Form1();` to a writeable property and set the value from the initial Form1. That way you're not creating a second form but you have access to Form1 methods from Form2.